# Finding $U(S,V,N)$ for ideal gas, given $pV=NkT$ and $U(T)=N c_V T$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Given the experimental results for the ideal gas, I want to recover the internal energy expressed in its natural variables as:

$$U(S,V,N) = \alpha e^{\frac{S}{N c_V}} V^{\frac{c_V-c_p}{c_V}} N^{\frac{c_p}{c_V}}$$

with $\alpha$ as some constant and $c_V,c_p$ the (intensive) heat capacities. My starting point are the two equations:

$$pV=(c_P-c_V)NT,$$
$$U=c_V NT.$$

These completely characterize the system, and so does any thermodynamic potential expressed in its 'natural' variables, so one should follow from the other. To recover the experimental facts from $U(S,V,N)$ is simple enough, but I'm interested in the other direction. Unfortunately I was unable to find this derivation anywhere - I found the formula mentioned on wikipedia but I can't get my hands on the books cited.

So, how to do it? I'm not at all interested in any statistical physics considerations, only pure thermodynamics. Preferably without any elaborate tricks, I believe this must be doable in a methodical manner with just straightforward (if tedious?) math, i.e. using with all the multivariable calculus identities (Jacobians etc.), and this is the method I'd like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite  the equations of the ideal gas to the energy U as a function of its natural variables, or to its *derivatives*. If you know how to related $p$ and $T$, to $U$, a simple mathematical operation can give you the expected result.

**Edit as the OP solves the problem:**

Using $\partial U/\partial S=T$ and the third equation of the OP's question, we find
$$U=f(N,V)e^{\frac{S}{c_V N}}.$$

Using $\partial U/\partial V=-p$ and the third equation of the OP's question, we find
$$U=f(N)V^{\frac{c_V-c_p}{c_V}}e^{\frac{S}{c_V N}}.$$

Finally, using the fact that the energy is extensive :
$$U(\lambda S,\lambda V, \lambda N)=\lambda U(S,V,N),$$
one finds that $f(N)\propto N^{\frac{c_p}{c_V}}$, which allows us to show that using only the thermodynamic equations of the ideal gas, we can find the energy as a function of the entropy, volume and number of particle.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this answer at all. How can I rewrite them in terms of $S$ for example?

Comment: @DepeHb: well, how do relate temperature, energy and entropy ?

Comment: $T = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_{V,N}$

Comment: @DepeHb: indeed. that should give you a way to get the first part of the result.

Comment: So from this I get $\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_{V,N} = U(S,V,N)/c_V N$, and $U(S,V,N) = f(N,V)e^{S/Nc_V}$, which is part of the result. Now I suppose I'll get something from p as well, but what about $\mu$? It doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: @DepeHb: Now, you just have to do the same with the volume !

Comment: I got $U = \alpha g(S,N) V^{1-\gamma}$. But now the third one, the derivative w.r.t $N$ is equal to $\mu$ which I don't know how to calculate.

Comment: @DepeHb: Well, it just means that you don't have enough equations to completely recover the equation. Maybe there is a standard thermodynamics equation to relate the energy and the change of particle.

Comment: I thought those two relations completely specified the ideal gas?

Comment: There are 3 variables, so you need 3 equations.

Comment: Perhaps some sort of extensivity argument can be used to determine f(N) then?

Comment: Yes I just checked and it works !! :)

Comment: @DepeHb: Indeed, well done !

Comment: The only question remains, how to determine the multiplicative constant in front of energy - and what does it depend on? Does this require further experimental measurements? From statistical mechanics (at least for free energy) one gets a constant involving $\hbar$ and $m$, which from classical thermodynamics seems to be impossible to predict theoretically. The $m$ dependence means this proportionality is different for every kind of ideal gas I guess?

Comment: Yes, you need stat-mech to find the constant, that does depends on $\hbar$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas#Ideal_Boltzmann_gas .