# Does $U(S,V,N) = \alpha e^{\frac{S}{N c_v}} V^{\frac{c_v-c_p}{c_v}} N^{\frac{c_p}{c_v}}$ really imply zero entropy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas

According to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210994/finding-us-v-n-for-ideal-gas-given-pv-nkt-and-ut-n-c-v-t), for some ideal gas

$$U(S,V,N) = \alpha e^{\frac{S}{N c_v}} V^{\frac{c_v-c_p}{c_v}} N^{\frac{c_p}{c_v}}$$

From this,

$$T = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} = \frac{1}{Nc_v}U \implies TS = \frac{S}{Nc_v}U$$
$$-P = \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} = \frac{c_v-c_p}{c_v}\frac{1}{V}U\implies -PV = \frac{c_v-c_p}{c_v}U$$
$$\mu = \frac{\partial U}{\partial N} = \frac{c_p}{c_v}\frac{1}{N}U\implies \mu N = \frac{c_p}{c_v}U$$

So, on one hand

$$TS -PV+\mu N= \left(\frac{S}{Nc_v} + \frac{c_v-c_p}{c_v} + \frac{c_p}{c_v}\right)U = \left(\frac{S}{Nc_v} + 1 \right)U$$
On the other hand, [by Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy?fbclid=IwAR1CyHUVl1h89yk-PthDNzbRRzckRyq_2s0FrvzumLxmNaJDgxk_Ib1PZOg#Internal_energy_of_multi-component_systems:%7E:text=using%20Euler%27s%20homogeneous,the%20internal%20energy%3A),
$$TS -PV+\mu N=U$$
which implies

$$\frac{S}{Nc_v} + 1 =1$$

that is,
$$S=0$$

Where is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In differentiation $\partial_N$ you didn't act on $\exp\left(\frac{S}{N c_v}\right)$.

**EDIT**
If you differentiate properly you'll get:
$$\mu = \frac{\partial U}{\partial N}=\frac{c_p}{c_v} \frac{U}{N} - \frac{S}{N c_v} \frac{U}{N},$$ where the second term cancels the problematic $\frac{S}{N c_v}$ term and yields the proper expression for the internal energy.