# What is the difference between an equation of state, and a state function?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, definition, ideal-gas

Wikipedia seems to list them as two different things, ([Equation of State](https://web.archive.org/web/20220909020748/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state), [State Function](https://web.archive.org/web/20220909102453/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function)); however, it seems like both pages are describing the same thing. Is there really any difference between the two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

State function is a *function* that depends only on the thermodynamic variables characterizing a state, but not on how we arrive to this state. E.g., the internal energy is a function
$$U(S,V,N)$$

Equation of state is an *equation*, which relates the thermodynamic variables. E.g., we know that the internal energy of the ideal gas is
$$
U=c_Vn T.
$$
Equating this expression with the function for the internal energy we obtain (after some math) the equation for the ideal gas, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy#Internal_energy_of_the_ideal_gas) (see also [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210994/247642) and [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/717814/247642)).